# Android Studio - Gradle build failed Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, build, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an odd problem with AS.  I have two OSX computers.  A simple app builds on one of them but not the other.  The two computers are almost identical.

Here are the specs of the two computers:

*OSX 10.8.5 - both fresh installed earlier this year.  Not upgraded from older version of OSX.
*JDK 1.8.0_05
*Android Studio 0.8.1 - both fresh installed
*Latest Android SDK.  The Android Studio SDK Manager looks exactly the same on both machines.

Here is how I build a test project:

1. Install fresh install of AS 0.8.0 for OSX
2. Upgrade to 0.8.1
3. Update SDKs
4. Start AS
5. Select New Project On "Configure your new project page", press Next button
6. On "Select form factors" page, press Next button
7. On "Add and activity" page, select Blank Activity and press Next button
8. On "Choose options" page, press Finish
9. Let AS build new project
10. Close Tip of the Day
11. Press Run button

As you can see, this is letting AS build the most basic template.

On one computer the build fails.  On the other computer it succeeds and I can run the project in the emulator.  On both computers I can Sync with Gradle and the Gradle build finishes.
On one computer, the build fails when click Run.  I have compared the gradle.build files and, of course they are the same.  They were both built by AS.

I am assuming something has been installed on the failing computer that prevents the build.  How can I "reset" the failing computer?  Would uninstalling JDK help?  I have deleted AS many times and that does not help.  I am not sure how to uninstall the various SDK components.

Here is the error messages I get when I Run on the failing computer:

Build fails with following output:

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
2014-07-07 21:30:45.482 java[19889:1603] Connection with distnoted server was invalidated
2014-07-07 21:30:45.542 java[19889:4103] Connection with distnoted server was invalidated
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output /Users/clark/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug /Users/clark/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug /Users/clark/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug
>     Error Code:
>       1
>     Output:
>       2014-07-07 21:30:45.482 java[19889:1603] Connection with distnoted server was invalidated
>       2014-07-07 21:30:45.542 java[19889:4103] Connection with distnoted server was invalidated
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1.514 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Gradle Console shows following error:

Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.441 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
2014-07-07 21:30:45.482 java[19889:1603] Connection with distnoted server was invalidated
2014-07-07 21:30:45.542 java[19889:4103] Connection with distnoted server was invalidated

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
  >   /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output /Users/clark/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug /Users/clark/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug /Users/clark/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug
  >   Error Code:
  >   1
  >   Output:
  >   2014-07-07 21:30:45.482 java[19889:1603] Connection with distnoted server was invalidated
  >   2014-07-07 21:30:45.542 java[19889:4103] Connection with distnoted server was invalidated
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.514 secs

Comment: I just discovered that I can build if I run AS as Administrator on the bad machine.  I do not have to do this on the good machine.  What could be different between the two machines that could cause this behavior?

Comment: I've the same problem, that happen just when I try to add the amazon aws-core and aws-s3 libs.. any idea about that?

Comment: My problem disappeared with the next version of Android Studio.  Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the 0.8.9. It seems that this error occur when you exceed the DEX limit of 65k methods. The only workaround I've found is to strip all the libs I'm using (eg, the last version of google_play_services lib contains like 20k method.. 1/3 of the space budget is gone!). So, this way I get the app work, but many times I've to run gradlew assembleDebug from shell (It doesn't work from android studio), and every time I checkout to another branch I've to clean and re-strip all the libs to get successful compilation. I'm looking forward for a better solution.. any help would be great!

Comment: I'm afraid you are beyond me.  I am just learning AS and my apps are very small.  In fact, I don't even know why DEX limit means.  Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: I don't know your build.gradle but can you check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27610280/2500784