# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, jar, android-support-library, build.gradle

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nifty.eattime.eattime"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-toq-api-1.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/firebase-client-android-2.0.3.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'


}
```

The error i am getting is:

Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/AndroidProject/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/20.0.0/dx --dex --output /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/android-toq-api-1.5.2-f889cb10fa3ffcf552ce25911647e19e8725882e.jar /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-058601ccc68d7ab3a25a4d7acfed330e991f63f0.jar /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/firebase-client-android-2.0.3-3c2b9f93968b42c99643d13191d90362745a12c2.jar /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/firebase-client-android-2.0.3-f7791b3ec0a8d11d755da5b7bca6b01657039ab3.jar /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/firebase-client-jvm-2.0.3-fc93a1dc76afe6f8e7657b91abe71118cd7dfb93.jar /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/jackson-annotations-2.2.2-9aa6cf2cfd800b7f8182b30d7eec54bd95d6b744.jar /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/jackson-core-2.2.2-1eb9bcfaba66967c860990f07408925462140191.jar /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/jackson-databind-2.2.2-5e8cbe8ca9e588d94b7577f0c6dd61ff811c42d9.jar /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.1.0-eead7e08439b52f014b0470eef9256c4660aa428.jar /Users/trungha/Documents/Projects/CS160/final_project/EatTime/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/tubesock-0.0.10-abbab7705f143b8d0d20df128b78e7b91fbf41f5.jar
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/firebase/client/android/AndroidCredentialStore;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

From what I read, it has to do with a duplication of dependencies. I tried to exclude com.android.support, but it does not work. Helps will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should delete

```
compile files('libs/android-toq-api-1.5.2.jar')
compile files('libs/firebase-client-android-2.0.3.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

leave only

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

I had the same error and I tried it, after that I had no more error.